# Blank page on application startup

Tags: performance, android-manifest, android-theme, android

How do I get rid of the blank page usually with the app name as a title that loads when you start up your application. I've done some reasearch and the best explanation/solution I found was to set the application's theme to null so the android system doesn't draw that page.

I have tried this but it doesn't work though in principle I think it should.

In my styles.xml I have

```
<style name="NoBackground" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

and in my manifest file I have

```
<application
    android:name=".FIXR"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/NoBackground" >
```

Is there a better way to get rid of this?

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to hide this view. This is created when the project is first created to give you a base. The java file and the xml layout file can be modified to suit your needs. This screen is created automatically and set within the manifest to be the launch activity, i.e. the screen that loads when the app is first launched

Comment: How can I edit this screen?

Comment: See my edit in answer, attached splashscreen

Comment: @GrayStatic you haven't explained what you are trying to do and what the user should see when you launch the app. When the project is created an activity file usually called MainActivity.java and a layout file main_activity.xml. In the Manifest it will have something like ``<Activity android:name=".MainActivity"...android.Launcher`` I can't remember the exact code top my head but somewhere it will say that activity is the launcher screen. I.e. when the app is first opened, this screen will always be shown

Comment: hai i got the same problem...If you solve this problem let me know what is the solution...

Answer (score 1):

If your application has Service or you run async tasks on `onCreate` method, show up splash screen with process dialog and after all sources loaded, switch to main screen. This is a technique.

To make you easy work I cut off part of my code:

**launcher.xml**

Actually its your Splash screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/splashscreen" 
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<ProgressBar 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
```

In your main Activity:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.launcher);

 mHandler = new Handler();

 //if Service is Ready: ....

 mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent().setClass(LaunchActivity.this, OtherActivity.class).setData(getIntent().getData()));
                finish();
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Hope it will help you to sort things out

Comment: Its actaully my splash screen causing this, I have stopped the heavy operations in this class but I still get this behaviour

Answer (score 1):

I use this and it is working for me

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.G"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_app"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    >
```

Comment: Maybe you are using another theme for your launcher activity.

Comment: No I haven't set themes for activities just for application

Answer (score 0):

I think its showing because Your app's first page takes time to load. it can be possible that you are doing too much of work on onCreate() method of activity. so i would suggest try to minimize the load when activity starts. so that blank screen will not appear.

Hope you understand!!

Comment: Yes I'm doing alot but it can't be helped, isn't there a work around?

Comment: what you are doing on activity load??

Comment: download a JSON file using async task

Comment: what i would suggest is that open splash screen for 2 3 sec. and then  open your activity and do background task so that it won't get blank screen. sometimes this happens when your app is also heavy loaded. means lots of drawables or layouts. at that time also it can happen.

Answer (score 0):

In the `style.xml` create:

```
<style name="SplashPage">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Then in the `AndroidManifest.xml` in your launcher activity, specify the activity theme:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:theme="@style/SplashPage"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below line of code, add these Lines in your res/values/styles.xml :

-------

```
<style name="SplashScreen">
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
</style>
```

And in your Manifest file Just pass that as style Under Your Activity tag as :

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name="com.mpg.myapp.MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashScreen"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

May be this will help you.